# Constant set from constant array in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, set, constants

So I have a constant array of chars like this:

```
const spCh:array[#1..#4]of char=('\','%','{','}');
```

I need also a set with all the elements from the array so I do this:

```
var h:char; spChrz:set of char;
...
  spChrz:=[];
  for h:=#1 to #4 do spChrz:=spChrz+[spCh[h]];
```

Is it possible somehow to define constant set from const array instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Arrays are always typed constants, and typed constants cannot be used to define other typed constants, such as your set.

Note that there is no performance advantage to a set defined the way you propose. Typed constants are accessed identically to ordinary variables, so you may as well keep the code you have to initialize the set from the array at run time.

Comment: Thx for clarification, just wondered if there r maybe some feature for set type i've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const spChz:set of char=['\','%','{','}'];
```

Comment: Such approach makes the whole thing useless. I have that const array to keep all the special characters for my parser in one place.
Plus it's just basic set const, so it's off-topic to "constant set from constant array" concept...

Comment: @Markus_13    _Is it possible somehow to define constant set instead?_ I answered the question as it is. You did not say that the array needs to be used to define the set

Comment: Ok, edited question to emphasize the main concept, if topic title isn't enough.